# How to block all ports except ssh

Tags: ssh, iptables, centos-6.9

I have changed ssh default port to 2020, And add iptable rule in order to allow incoming traffic on that port using below command.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2020 -j ACCEPT`

And i would like to block all other ports on the server. And use below command after allowing ssh. All session are closed. How can i fix it.

`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

`iptables -P OUTPUT DROP`

Comment: oh, sorry you are the original poster, I'll elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to enable OUTPUT

```
    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -F
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2020 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 2020 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -P INPUT DROP
    iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate it ?

Comment: @blaCkninJa yeah, sure

Comment: Okay, I will try it later and let you know.

Comment: @blaCkninJa OK, I'm not sure if OUTPUT DROP would cause a problem, you may need an output rule as well

Comment: Working but what if we also want to allow port 80 for apache server. ?

Comment: @blaCkninJa just duplicate the lines with "2020" with whatever other port you want to allow

Comment: thanks, I have used following iptables in order to allow incoming port 80 traffic.
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`


`iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`